# Why doesn't MyTermite work as expected in Java?

Tags: java

Say, I'm studying the book Think Java: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist by Allen B. Downey. In Chapter 10 GridWorld part 2 there is this termites example. I downloaded and imported these codes (links provided by the book):

http://thinkapjava.com/code/Termite.java

http://thinkapjava.com/code/Termite.gif

http://thinkapjava.com/code/TermiteRunner.java

http://thinkapjava.com/code/EternalFlower.java

as instructed and run MyTermite:

```
public class MyTermite extends Termite {
    public void act() {
        if (getGrid() == null)
            return;
        if (seeFlower()) {
            pickUpFlower();
        }
        if (hasFlower()) {
            dropFlower();
        }
        if (canMove()) {
            move();
        }
        randomTurn();
    }
}
```

in Eclipse, but MyTermite neither picks up flowers nor drop them, which is supposed to be so. All codes are imported and MyTermite is copied from the book. I tried to debug but unable to find any clue.

Comment: Have you edited the `TermiteRunner` class so it instantiates your `MyTermite` class? E.g. Change this line: `Termite alice = new Termite();` to `MyTermite alice = new MyTermite();` and be sure to do the same for `bob`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I thought the extends method had done the job.